# How to resolve "django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'activate' not found."

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I'm currently working on a local project using Django 4.2 as backend. I'm trying to do account activation based on email. Below is my code snippet.

**Project *urls.py***

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from .auth_token import CustomAuthToken

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls')),
    path('api-token-auth/', CustomAuthToken.as_view()),
    path('portal-user/api/', include('portal_user.urls', namespace="portal_user"))
]
```

**portal_user *urls.py***

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import activate

app_name = "portal_user"

urlpatterns = [
    path(
        'activate/<slug:uidb64>/<slug:token>/', activate, name="account-activate"),
]
```

**portal_user views.py**

```
def send_account_activation_mail(self):
    mail_subject = 'Welcome to Our Platform! Activate Your Account'
    mail_message = render_to_string('portal_user/account_activate_email.html', {
        "first_name": f"{self.first_name}!",
        "uidb": urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(self.pk)),
        "token": account_activation_token.make_token(self),
        "activate_url": CLIENT_DOMAIN
    })

    try:
        email = EmailMessage(
            subject=mail_subject, body=mail_message, to=[self.email]
        )
        email.content_subtype = "html"
        email.send()
    except BadHeaderError:
        return HttpResponse("Invalid header found!")
    except Exception as e:
        return HttpResponse("Something went wrong!")


def activate(request, uidb64, token):
    try:
        uid = force_str(urlsafe_base64_decode(uidb64))
        user = PortalUser.objects.get(pk=uid)
    except (TypeError, ValueError, OverflowError, PortalUser.DoesNotExist):
        user = None

    if user is not None and account_activation_token.check_token(user, token):
        user.is_active = True
        user.save()
        return Response({"message": "activation_successful"}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
    else:
        return Response({"message": "activation_failed"}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

**Account Activation Mail Template *account_activate_email.html***

```
<a href="{{ activate_url }}{% url 'portal_user:account-activate' uidb64=uid token=token %}">
    {{ activate_url }}{% url 'portal_user:account-activate' uidb64=uid token=token %}
</a>
```

Whenever I'm trying to send email to users using ***send_account_activation_mail*** function  provided in **portal_user *views.py***, it throws error

> django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'account-activate' with keyword arguments '{'uidb64': '', 'token': 'bshs4w-028ce1c25d313eeaaeb81e3cac46535d'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['portal\-user/api/activate/(?P[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/(?P[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/\Z']`

and if I remove the namespace from template, then it throws error

> `django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'account-activate' not found. 'account-activate' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

I have spent hours on google regarding these error but unable to solve. I'm not getting where I'm going wrong. If anyone have solution to this issue, please let me know.

Comment: Namespace is required, the first error is thrown because `uidb64` is empty. When you pass it from the view you call it `uidb`, in the template you refer to it as `uid` (here: `uidb64=uid token=token`). Just a typo in the template (or view).

Comment: Thanks, @IvanStarostin. It worked. I was trying to solve the issue for hours but was not able to do. Once again, thanks a lot.